# Mantra for gaining children

Tags: atharva-veda

I am referring to this book Исцеляющие мантры в Аюрведе (Russian Edition) (Healing Mantras in Ayurveda). There is a Mantra for gaining children. It is said, that this Mantra is written in Atharvaveda. I sounds like this:

```
Yena Vahad Babhivitha
Nashaymasi Tat Tvam Idam
Tadaniyatra Tvadaha Dure Nidadhmasi
```

Sorry for maybe wrong spelling as in this book Mantra is written in Cyrillic.

Would you please write this Mantra for me in Sanskrit so I can get right pronunciation?
Also you are welcome to suggest me other Mantras for gaining children.
Thank you!

Comment: You can't just pick any mantra from a book and start to chant, you need to get initiation from a teacher (who received inititation from his teacher... ). It should be like an unbroken chain of teacher-disciple starting from Lord/Rishi himself... Further in case of Vedic Mantras they need to be chanted in extremely precise way matching all swaras....

Comment: Such mantras should be pronounced by Brahmins who are well versed in both sanskrit pronunciation and in the Atharva veda. If you try on your own and you mispronounce, it can lead to the opposite result....

Comment: I'd advise to read the whole Atharvaveda from an authentic source https://www.kritinova.in/collections/pbb/products/a-complete-set-of-all-four-vedas-english-kritinova. However, a guru would be very meaningful to practice them. It's not as simple as it seems.